# PHP: using strip_tags with parameters with array_map

Tags: php, strip-tags, array-map

I've looked at other posts but can't seem to get to a working solution in place to the point where I am now looking at a blank canvas.

```
$l = array_map( 'strip_tags', $l );
```

This is what I currently have but I would like to keep `<p>, <a>, <ul> and <li>` tags

Comment: Pass an anonymous function to array_map, and inside that function call strip_tags with the appropriate parameters. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: What is $l? is it an array or a string?

Comment: Yes it is an array

Answer (score 4):

If `$l` is an array,
First of all, avoid to affect to the variable the output of a function with which you pass the variable itself

you can write something like this:

```
$output = array_map(function($item) {
    return strip_tags($item, '<p><a><ul><li>');
}, $l)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to JessGabriel's answer:

Starting in PHP 8.1, you can't pass NULLs to internal function parameters (https://php.watch/versions/8.1/internal-func-non-nullable-null-deprecation). So for strip_tags, I have a quick and dirty if statement so it doesn't toss an error:

```
$output= array_map(function($v){ 
        if (is_null($v)) { 
            $v = '';
        }
        return trim(strip_tags($v));
    }, $myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**From PHP 8.1, you have to use it like this:**

```
$output = array_map(function($item) {
    return strip_tags((string) $item, '<p><a><ul><li>');
}, $l)
```