# Array_Map and Strip_Tags expecting string

Tags: php, arrays

PHP Version: 8.1

Hello,
I’m trying to implement strip tags on a passed in JSON object that looks like this (just inputting one transaction for brevity):

```
"{"request":"transactions","id":1,"transactions":[{"date":"2022-11-09","amount":5000,"amount2":2000,"amount3":null,"amount4":null}]}"
```

I perform json_decode on this object:

```
 $decoded = json_decode($content_raw, true));
```

and get the following:

```
request: "transactions"
id: 1
transactions: array(1)
   0: array(5)
     date: "2022-11-09"
     amount: 5000
     amount2: 2000
     amount3: null
     amount4: null
```

I then want to strip tags to make sure no one is passing in anything malicious, so I follow the procedure in accordance with php 8.1 in this thread.

[PHP: using strip_tags with parameters with array_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270072/php-using-strip-tags-with-parameters-with-array-map)

```
$decoded_clean = array_map(function($v)
    { 
        if (is_null($v)) { //can't pass null into strip_tags starting in php8.1, so have to give a ''
            $v = '';
        }
        return trim(strip_tags($v)); //PROBLEM IS HERE
    }, $decoded['transactions']);
//now that strip_tags is present, replace '' with NULL so the DB will store non-number decimals (i.e., NULL). This is because the database defaults '' to 0.000.
   foreach($decoded_clean as $key=>$array_value) { //key=>value
        if ($array_value=='') { $decoded_clean[$key] = NULL; }
    }

extract($decoded_clean); //this creates a list of variables that are in the array with the name of their key. This makes it easier than having to call $decoded['variable_name'] every time
```

However, the strip tags function is causing problems and tossing out: “PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strip_tags(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\...”

If I make $decoded a string, I then have a problem with array_map expecting an array. What am I doing wrong with my syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: `$decoded['transactions']` is __array__.

Comment: Just tried, no luck... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strip_tags(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in C:\\xampp\\htdocs. Updated code to reflect change.

Comment: Also each item of `$decoded['transactions']` is __array__ too.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, how would my code change to address that comment?

Comment: Why are you mucking about with `strip_tags`? If you need to validate the data, validate it for what it's supposed to be. Is a date actually a valid date? Are your numeric fields actually numeric values? `strip_tags` does nothing for you if a date field contains `"This is a date"`. Tags in text are only a problem if your code doesn't handle text properly on output. What you're doing is just a waste of time.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular—some fields allow freestyle writing. I felt have strip tags procedure would be the best way vs writing the function from scratch. I understand what you mean for numerical fields.

Comment: @TechJunkie If you're handling your output properly then tags in free text fields are not a problem. If you're not handling your output properly then you have more to worry about than tags. Either way, `strip_tags` is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `array_walk_recursive` with passing argument by reference:

```
array_walk_recursive($decoded, function(&$v) { 
    if (is_null($v)) {
        $v = '';
    } else {
        $v = trim(strip_tags($v));
    }
});
```